# How do you iterate through a list that is set in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, code-behind

I need to loop through a list on an aspx webpage. It's part of an object that is populated in the code behind. All of the other properties of the object are strings and I can access them like so:

```
<td align="center"><%# Eval("PartNumber") %></td>
```

or

```
<td align="center"><%# Eval("ContractNumber") %></td>
```

I was trying to do something like the following with the list:

```
<% List<PeriodData> periodValues = (List<PeriodData>)Eval("PeriodValues");
   foreach (var period in periodValues)
   {
       Response.Write("<td align='center'>");
       period.ETC.ToString("#,0.#");
       Response.Write("</td>");
   }
%>
```

I get this error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would put a repeater on the page, and then bind your List to it in the code behind.

Comment: That makes it look like the first two are part of some repeater or other databound control but the third one isn't. That's the problem. `Eval` refers to the underlying item bound to the control. But if you use it outside of a databound control, there is no item for it to refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the entire report table in the code behind using a StringBuilder and setting a label's text field to the built up string. Not the most elegant solution and not how I wanted to handle it, but, hey, it works.